# I'm trying to select a specific option from select with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have a select list with 4 options. 
What I want is to hide the submit button when I select the first option with the `value="zero"`. When I select the other options "one", "two", "three".... I want the submit button to be displayed. This is my first time on programming and I dont know what to do. Please give some help... Thanks!!!!

```js
$('.wizardActionStaRate').change(function() {

  var firstItem = $('select [value="zero"]')

  if ($(firstItem)) {
    $('.starate').hide();
  } else {
    $('.starate').show()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> . 
</script>
<select class="wizardActionStaRate">
  <option value="zero"></option>
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
<div class="buttonsContainer">
  <div class="btn btn-rect rate">
    <p class="numbers">Submit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few changes:

1. Getting the value using `this` var. `this` mean the select DOM
   node because `$('.wizardActionStaRate')` selects it.
2. Fix the button selector to `.btn`. `starate` class does not exists.
3. Trigger the change to force running the code.

```js
$('.wizardActionStaRate')
.change(function() {
  if (this.value === 'zero') {
    $('.btn').hide();
  } else {
    $('.btn').show();
  }
})
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="wizardActionStaRate">
  <option value="zero"></option>
  <option value="one">1</option>
  <option value="two">2</option>
  <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
<div class="buttonsContainer">
  <div class="btn btn-rect rate">
    <p class="numbers">Submit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lucas Marques 
Thank you!!!! This is works!!!! I'm over 14 hours and trying to make it work.... Thanks!!!!!!!!!]

Comment: @DimitrisT., you are welcome. Everyone starts with the basic. Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the `selected` option with something like this:

```
var theSelection = $(".wizardActionStaRate > option:selected");
```

Then you can inspect that within your `change()` function:

```
$('.wizardActionStaRate').change(function() {
    var theSelection = $(".wizardActionStaRate > option:selected");
    if ($(theSelection).val() == "zero") {
        $('.btn').hide();
    } else { 
        $('.btn').show();
    }
});
```

I suggest giving your button an ID, and that way you'll be able to hide/show it with more precision.  E.g., to hide a button with id=dimitris, you could use `$('#dimitris').hide();`